# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, clang, boost-json

I am getting a linking error with my two C++ files as seen below.
[Compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pry69.png)

It compiles up to the point of two object files then fails on linking.

Below is my code, I commented out most of main in order to isolate the issue.

I am using the boost/JSON library. The duplicates are all from the boost JSON library.

The JSONParser file is going to take in a JSON object and turn it to a C++ object but I don't think anything to do with the actual code is the issue. Just either a library or header file issue.

main.cpp

```
#include "JSONParser.hpp"
/*
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

namespace net = boost::asio;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
using namespace boost::beast;
using namespace boost::beast::websocket;

*/

int main (void) {

  //net::io_context ioc;
  //tcp_stream sock(ioc);
  //net::ssl::context ctx(net::ssl::context::tlsv12);

}
```

JSONParser.hpp

```
#ifndef JSONPARSER_H
#define JSONPARSER_H

#define BOOST_JSON_STACK_BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>

class candlestick{
    private:
        double openPrice;
        double closePrice;
        double priceHigh;
        double priceLow;
        double baseVolume;
        double quoteVolume;
        bool isClosed;

    public:
        candlestick (double oP, double cP, double pH, double pL, double bV, double qV, bool iC);

        void setopenPrice(double p) {
            openPrice = p;
        }
        double getopenPrice(void) {
            return openPrice;
        }
        void setclosePrice(double p) {
            closePrice = p;
        }
        double getclosePrice(void) {
            return closePrice;
        }
        void setpriceHigh(double p) {
            priceHigh = p;
        }
        double getpriceHigh(void) {
            return priceHigh;
        }
        void setpriceLow(double p) {
            priceLow = p;
        }
        double getpriceLow(void) {
            return priceLow;
        } 
        void setbaseVolume(double v) {
            baseVolume = v;
        }
        double getbaseVolume(void) {
            return baseVolume;
        }
        void setquoteVolume(double v) {
            quoteVolume = v;
        }
        double getquoteVolume(void) {
            return quoteVolume;
        } 
        void setClosed(bool c) {
            isClosed = c;
        }
        bool getClosed(void) {
            return isClosed;
        }
};

candlestick::candlestick (double oP, double cP, double pH, double pL, double bV, double qV, bool iC) {
        openPrice = oP;
        closePrice = cP;
        priceHigh = pH;
        priceLow = pL;
        baseVolume = bV;
        quoteVolume = qV;
        isClosed = iC;
};

candlestick createCandlestickObject ();

#endif
```

JSONParser.cpp

```
#include "JSONParser.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

candlestick createCandlestickObject () {
    candlestick c (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, true);

    return c;
}
```

By commenting out the #include "JSONParser.hpp" out of main, I was able to remove the error, therefore definitely a linking issue.

Comment: You implement `candlestick::candlestick(...)` as non-`inline` function in a header which will result in an issue like this, if you include the header in more than one translation unit and link. Either move the definition inside the class body, or add the `inline` modifier to the implementation outside of the class. Not sure if this solves all the linker issues though...

Comment: thanks, moved the constructor definition into the class body however still have the same issue with linking.

Comment: The `boost/json/src.hpp` you included has a comment at the top that it is supposed to be included exactly one in the program. Did you mean to `#include <boost/json.hpp>` instead?